# How do I add these images that provide information about a repository or package in a github repo?

Tags: github, npm

So, I have seen a lot of packages with these images:

[image: Example]

I could not find a way to add them, does anyone know how to add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example in this [repository](https://github.com/flaxel/parser) for the license:

```
[![License Apache-2.0](https://img.shields.io/badge/license-Apache--2.0-blue.svg)](LICENSE)
```

You can create more badges with [Shield.io](https://shields.io/). Therefore you can easily copy your url and get the possible result:

[image]